# What is the derivative using the Chain Rule...?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

My question is:

Find the derivative of $f(x)=((x^2 + 3)^5 + x)^2$

I know that the answer is $20x(x^2 + 3)^9 + 2(x^2 + 3)^5 + 20x^2(x^2 + 3)^4 + 2x$

But when I try working out the problem myself, I get:

$20x(x^2 + 3)^9 + 2x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain rule says:

$\frac{d}{dx}u^n=n*u^{n-1}*\frac{du}{dx}$

Meaning, if you have $(x^2+3)^3$, the derivative of that would be $3 * (x^2+3)^2 * 2x$.

Let's now get to your example:

$f(x)=((x^2 + 3)^5 + x)^2$

Step one, chain rule:

$f'(x)=2*((x^2+3)^5+x)*(\frac{d}{dx}((x^2+3)^5+x))$

Oh no! We'll have to do the chain rule again! Because:

$\frac{d}{dx}((x^2+3)^5+x)=\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+3)^5+\frac{d}{dx}x=\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+3)^5+1$

Chain rule again!

$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+3)^5=5*(x^2+3)^4*2x$

Substituting that back to the equation~

$f'(x)=2*((x^2+3)^5+x)*(5*(x^2+3)^4*2x + 1)$

This is getting a bit messy, but...

$f'(x)=(2(x^2+3)^5+2x)*(10x(x^2+3)^4 + 1)=20x(x^2+3)^9+2(x^2+3)^5+20x^2(x^2+3)^4+2x$

By FOILing.

Cheers!
-Shahar

Comment: Hats off to you Sir.

Comment: @BrianP. Thanks! Hope my work makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

By the chain rule $(f\circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$

Then look the functions $f_1=x^2$, $f_2=(x^2+3)^5+x$ then $f(x)=f_1\circ f_2$ so $f'(x)=f_1'(f_2(x))f_2'(x)=2(f_2(x))f_2(x)'$
Now $f_2'=((x^2+3)^5+x)'=((x^2 +3)^3)'+x'=(f_3\circ f_4)'+1 $ Where $f_3 =x^3$ and $f_4=x^2+3$ so $(f_3\circ f_4)'=f_3'(f_4(x))f_4'(x)=5(x^2+3)^4(2x)$ Putting it together gives$$f'(x)=2((x^2+3)^5+x)(5(x^2+3)^4(2x)+1)=2(10x(x^2+3)^9+(x^2+3)^5+10x^2(x^2+3)^4+x)$$